# Give Access to folder(s) with LDAP authentification to certain OUs with Apache?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ldap, authorization

I want to make a web directory protectde by htaccess and LDAP users in certain OU's can access it.
I've googled all day and I couldn't make it happen. I've using Apache 2.2 on Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS. Here is my htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "LOGIN"
AuthUserFile /dev/null
AuthBasicProvider ldap
AuthzLDAPAuthoritative on
AuthLDAPURL "ldap://SERVER_IP/ou=users,dc=domain,dc=TLD,dc=ccTLD?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)"
AuthLDAPBindDN "cn=user,dc=domain,dc=TLD,dc=ccTLD"
AuthLDAPBindPassword passwd

#I've tried all of below:


#Require valid-user # This works just fine. But i don't want everyone can login.

#Require ldap-group ou=couldLogIn,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=TLD,dc=ccTLD # Tried this one and failed.

Require ldap-filter (ou=couldLogIn,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=TLD,dc=ccTLD)  # tried this one and also failed.
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. You shouldn't use brackets around the ldap-filter attribute.

This:

```
Require ldap-filter (ou=couldLogIn,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=TLD,dc=ccTLD)
```

Should be like this:

```
Require ldap-filter ou=couldLogIn,ou=users,dc=domain,dc=TLD,dc=ccTLD
```